# Delete corner of square in inkscape to turn it in to a triangle

Tags: inkscape

I have created a square using the square draw tool in inkscape and I want to delete one of its corners to make a triangle however when I select it with the edit path by nodes tool I am unable to remove any of the nodes like I would be able to with a bézier curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked this out after a bit of messing around but I have to convert the shape to a path by pressing `Path -> object to path`. I was then able to edit the nodes like normal.